# google temperature information

Tags: json, google-search, google-weather-api

Google has a weather box whenever you search for weather or temperature which gives info about your town and the temperature, wind and other there. Is there a way to get that data into a json variable ?

Comment: First google link searching for "json variable google weather" http://openweathermap.org/api

Comment: i think that is a different service than the one google provides

Comment: Very valid point. Apologies...

Comment: It is not listed here: https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/directory Might indicate that it is not a google API?

Answer (score 0):

Google doesnt have an JSON api for their weather service.I prefer using [openweather api](http://openweathermap.org/api) which gives you a simple and easy to use json interface.Or you can create the json objects yourself if you prefer doing it in the harder way.[here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-weather) is an example on how to use google map weather layer.